# What would happen if I tried to launch Bigby's Hand with the Catapult spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

The [*catapult*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/catapult) spell description says:

> Choose one object weighing 1 to 5 pounds within range that isn’t being worn or carried.

The description of [*Bigby's hand*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bigbys-hand) states that it is a Large object with no defined weight, but it doesn't fill the space it's in (I'm not sure if that means it's hovering or if it's ghostly).

Let's say I target *Bigby's hand* with *catapult* and launch the hand 90 feet towards some bad guys. **Would it fail as a possible use for *catapult*, or would it shoot off as normal and hit the first thing in its path?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Unknown, but may not be a legitimate object

[Catapult](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/catapult) doesn't require an object to weigh less than 5 lbs, but that it must weigh between 1 and 5 lbs.

> Choose one object weighing 1 to 5 pounds within range that isn’t being worn or carried.

Bigby has no defined weight and doesn't technically apply.

Comment: A valid point, thanks for pointing that out.  Since Bigby's Hand could very well grapple things, would it still no longer be a possible target if it was holding, say, a 1 pound dagger?  Or, alternatively, is a 1/2 pound bag holding 3 pounds of gold a valid target?

Comment: @DanielZastoupil, you should edit your question to include this comment.

Comment: I actually think that needs to be its own question about whether a collection of objects counts as a single object for catapult targets.

Comment: I think, technically, even with a dagger, catapult will not work because you cannot use the spell on items being worn or carried. I believe that the dagger is considered as "carried" by the hand.